# jquery ajax call datatype text return with data white space

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

This below code is working fine locally and working fine on the srver after hosted on IIS. but when I access from the client via chrome it return data with lot of white space always. why its behaving like this?

```
function GetData(PostUrl) {
    var Result = [];
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: "POST",
        url: PostUrl,
        data: "{}",
        contentType: "text/javascript",            
        dataType: "text",            
        success: function (data) {
            Result = data;
        },           
        error: function (data) { 
            var r = data.responseText;
            var errorMessage = r.Message;               
            $.confirm({
                animation: 'rotate', type: 'orange',
                title: 'Error!',
                content: 'A network-related error occurred! Please log off and try again.',
                buttons: {
                    yes: function () {  //confirm
                        window.onload = window.history.forward(0);
                        window.location = '../';
                    },
                }
            }); 
        }
    });
    return Result;
}
```

Comment: Could you pls show us a screenshot about your `white space`? And how you write your view?

Comment: On the server side, we return value only as "True". however from the client side we received "True                                                                       " (with extra white space added in it). this issue occurs in Testing environment but it works as correctly in other environment(dev environment).. Kindly give suggestion to solve the issue.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think it may relate to `contentType: "text/javascript"`, you may try to remove this line for a try. By the way, if it doesn't influnce the usage, you may use `$.trim()` to remove the spaces....

Comment: My pleasure sir : )